# When is this function differentiable $g(x)=(a +|x|)^2 \cdot e^{(5-|x|)^2}$?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Given a function :
$$g(x)=(a +|x|)^2 \cdot e^{(5-|x|)^2}$$

Find the values of $a$ for which the function is continuous in $\mathbb R$ and the values for which it is differentiable.

The function should be continuous for all $a \in \mathbb R$ since $|x|$ is continuous in $ \mathbb R$ whatever be the value of  $a$.
I want to know for what values of $a$ is this function differentiable?

Comment: Let $|x|= \sqrt{x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\neq0$, we have
$$g'\left(x\right)=e^{\left(5-|x|\right)^2}\left(2\text{ sign}\left(x\right)\left(a+|x|\right)-2\text{ sign}\left(x\right)\left(5-|x|\right)\left(a+|x|\right)^2\right).$$
You can differentiate on the open set $\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$, no matter what $a$ is.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I know that. But according to the question the function should be differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Thus, I feel that there is no value of $a$ such that $g(x)$ is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: If $a$ is constant, then the above formula is correct. Now, as you said, there is no value of $a$ such that $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$ because there is no value of $a$ such that $|x|$ is differentiable at $0$.